# Terminal Server Netmiko Connection

Tags: python, network-programming, netmiko

I am trying to make automate deployment which will be provided to remote configuration of devices and i am stuck not knowing what is wrong.

I am not an expert, just a beginner learning Python.

my Setup.

PythonServer--ssh- > Cisco Console Server --reverse tenet --> New_device(cisco)

I can successfully connect to the cisco colse server. (easy part, i can connect using device_type as 'cisco_ios', 'cisco_ios_telnet' , terminal_server', 'generic_terminal_server') all of them work.

when i try to reverse telnet, i get prompted with just password.

```
************************************************************************
This is a privately owned computing system.  Access permitted only by
authorized employees.
************************************************************************
Password:
```

I am unable to get past this. here is my code. What am i doing wrong? (i assume its got to do with the way netmiko handles the connections) and can someone help me fix this.

```
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler, redispatch

conserver_username = 'cisco'
conserver_password = 'cisco'
conserver_ip = '10.88.77.152'

console_server = {
    'host': conserver_ip,
    'username': conserver_username,
    'password': conserver_password,
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'session_log': 'log.out'
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**console_server)

net_connect.send_command('\n', expect_string=r'#')
net_connect.send_command('telnet 10.88.77.152 2004', expect_string=r':')
net_connect.send_command_timing('cisco')
#net_connect.send_command_timing('cisco')
net_connect.send_command_timing('\n')
```

This prompts me with banner and does not proceed.

I believe the module looks for username and since it is not presented with username, does not know how to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

there might be 2 issues:

1. if the device do not require password upon logging in (password configured in vty lines). This would be config issue on the Cisco ios
2. Instead of send_command try write_channel to establish connection. You may want to try the below code, I added some printing to help with the debug. Also, check your log file:

```
import time
from netmiko import ConnectHandler, redispatch

conserver_username = 'cisco'
conserver_password = 'cisco'
conserver_ip = '10.88.77.152'

console_server = {
    'host': conserver_ip,
    'username': conserver_username,
    'password': conserver_password,
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'session_log': 'log.out'
}

new_device_username = 'cisco'
new_device_password = 'cisco'

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**console_server)

#to make sure that you are in logged in to the right device:
output = net_connect.find_prompt()
print(output)
# write channel
net_connect.write_channel('telnet 10.88.77.152 2004')
time.sleep(2) # this is needed for the device to send response. Yoiu may adjust timing depending on your end device
output = net_connect.read_channel()
print(output)

#send username:
net_connect.write_channel(new_device_username)
time.sleep(2)
#send password:
net_connect.write_channel(new_device_password)
time.sleep(2)
output = net_connect.read_channel()
print(output)

#see if you are logged in
net_connect.write_channel('\n')
time.sleep(1)
output = net_connect.read_channel()
print(output)
#redispatch when logged in and use as normal:
redispatch(net_connect, device_type='cisco_ios_telnet')
output = net_connect.find_prompt()
print(output)
```

Note: there is a redispatch method!

You may want to have a look at [this](https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/automation/netmiko-proxy.html) article about Proxy

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to add

```
net_connect.write_channel("\r\n")
```

to provide a return/enter key function after entering the username and password.

```
net_connect.write_channel(new_device_username)
time.sleep(2)
net_connect.write_channel("\r\n")
```

and

```
net_connect.write_channel(new_device_password)
time.sleep(2)
net_connect.write_channel("\r\n")
```